# How to change color of range pixel with drawstring method depending percentage

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently using a splashscreen in my program and then I display info on it like download percentage of a file. I would like do like `JProgressBar` string, I mean, when the blue progress passes above the string, the color of the string changes.

Here the code that I'm currently using.

```
private static void splashProgress(float percent, String str)
{
    if (mySplash != null && mySplash.isVisible())
    {   // important to check here so no other methods need to know if there
        // really is a Splash being displayed
        float width = (186*percent)/100;
        splashProgress = new Rectangle2D.Double(4., 211., width, 24.);
        splashTextArea = new Rectangle2D.Double(width+4., 211., 186.-width, 24.);

        splashGraphics.setColor(new Color(255,177,100,255));
        splashGraphics.fill(splashProgress);

        splashGraphics.setColor(new Color(175,25,25,255));
        splashGraphics.fill(splashTextArea);
        splashGraphics.setColor(new Color(25,25,25,255));
        splashGraphics.drawString(str, 4,226);


        // make sure it's displayed
        mySplash.update();
    }
}
```

Progress bar looks like this :

[image]

As you can see, the string have the same color that the progress bar and I woulld like set color of the hidden part in a different color.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language.

Comment: I believe you need to set the `XORMode` of the `Graphics` context

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, XORMode seems to be good but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: All I was googled it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make use of `Graphics2D#setXORMode`

[image: XORMode]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestGraphics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGraphics();
    }

    public TestGraphics() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(new Color(175,25,25,255));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(new Color(255,177,100,255));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
            g2d.setXORMode(new Color(175,25,25,255));
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            String text = "I'm some exciting text";
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight()- fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried but as you can seen below the result is not what I expected :D

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnghr.png

The string disappeared and the progressbar doesn't reload itself correctly.
Here is my code if you know what is wrong.

```
private static void splashProgress(float percent, String str)
{
    if (mySplash != null && mySplash.isVisible())
    {   // important to check here so no other methods need to know if there
        // really is a Splash being displayed
        float width = (186*percent)/100;
        splashProgress = new Rectangle2D.Double(4., 211., width, 24.);
        splashTextArea = new Rectangle2D.Double(width+4., 211., 186.-width, 24.);

        splashGraphics.setColor(new Color(255,177,100,255));
        splashGraphics.fill(splashProgress);

        splashGraphics.setColor(new Color(175,25,25,255));
        splashGraphics.fill(splashTextArea);

        splashGraphics.setXORMode(new Color(175,25,25,255));
        splashGraphics.drawString(str, 4,226);

        // make sure it's displayed
        mySplash.update();
    }
}
```

and this method is called from there

```
while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0){
            writeFile.write(buffer, 0, read);
            writeFile.flush();
            percent = (percent + read);
            percentText = (int) ((percent*100)/length);
            splashProgress((percent*100)/length, "Téléchargement : "+percentText+" %");
        }
```

Nevertheless, big thanks for your help :)

EDIT : I tried to `setXorMode` outside my while loop and now this is what I get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrQcj.png

EDIT 2 : Ok I solved my problem, in fact there was a conflict because of my loop, so I just added `splashGraphics.setPaintMode();` for draw rectangle and then `splashGraphics.setXORMode(c);` for my text and it works perfectly.

Many thanks for your help and your reactivity.